# Why is my insert command not changing the database?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb, oledbcommand

im performing an insert sql command in c# program using oledb methods as the code down will show.

the action is performed and it even shows me a message I've put there to indicate if it worked or not but when i open the database manually the data i inserted using the code don't appear

im using c# and Acess as database

the tables in the database of type

**time = time/date**

**header = text**

**importance = int**

**body = text**

as for the variables in the code all string but im using a datetimepicker to allow the user to choose the date by picking instead of typing it

```
OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = Database.accdb");
conn1.Open();
string sql = "INSERT INTO notes ([time], [Header], [importance], [body])" + "VALUES ('" + dateTimePicker1.Value + "', '" + textBox1.Text + "','" + int.Parse(comboBox1.Text) + "','" + textBox2.Text + "');";
OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn1);
try
{
    OleDbDataReader rd2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
    conn1.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Added");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
this.Close();
```

Comment: guys i changed the command execution it makes sense but it's not working i'll update the code

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery() function is used to insert the data into database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem1 :** You are calling `ExecuteReader()` method while Inserting Data into Database.

**Solution1 :** You need to use `ExecuteNonQuery()` method to execute `INSERT`,`UPDATE` or `DELETE` commands.

Replace This :

```
OleDbDataReader rd2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
```

With This:

```
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**Problem 2:** you are assigning the `DateTime` value into `time` column as string. if the string format is not supported by `time` column then INSERT operation will not be successfull.

**Solution 2:**
so i would suggest you to use `Parameterised queries` for following two reasons:

1. mainly `parameterised queries` prevent `SQL Injection Attacks` to happen.
2. `parameterised queries` will send the `parameters` with proper datatypes.

**Suggestion :** while checking for the command execution status you need to read the return value of the `ExecuteNonQuery()` method.because it returns the total number of rows inserted into table after command execution. so you can read it and display success message only when the count returned is greater than zero.

**Complete Code:**

```
    int status=0;
    OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = Database.accdb");
    conn1.Open();
    string sql = "INSERT INTO notes ([time], [Header], [importance], [body]) " + "VALUES (?,?,?,?);";
    OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn1);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time",dateTimePicker1.Value);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Header",textBox1.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@importance",int.Parse(comboBox1.Text) );
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@body",textBox2.Text);
    try
    {
       status=cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
       conn1.Close();
       if(status>0)
       MessageBox.Show("INSERT Command Executed Successfully!");
       else
       MessageBox.Show("INSERT Command Failed!");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    this.Close();
```

Comment: @user3261119: you need to send DateTime value properly check my answer with `solution2`

Comment: iv tried the solution 2 and got baig list of errors from the catch exception message box i'll write down the errors give me som time :)

Comment: System.data.Oledb.oledbexception (0x80040e07) data type mismatch in criteria expression at                                                                               System.Data.Oledboledbcommand.executecommandtexterrorhandeling(oledbHresult hr)                                                                        at                                                                                      system data.oledb.oledbcommand.executecommandtextfor singleresult(tagDBP ARAMs db params Object & execute result

Comment: is there is a better way to pass date into database

Comment: @user3261119: i think OLEDB does not allow named parameters as it uses positional parameters so give ? question marks instead of named parameters in insert uery , check my edited answer.

Comment: not working but i noticed something when im using the current date it shows error but when i choose another date it shows it succeeded but it dont insert the data currently im so confused

Comment: hey dude your method worked but with the addition of a simple line of code add this line to mark your answear as correct and thanks                       "String date = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");"                           and then use date in the parameters

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ExecuteNonQuery` to execute the insert query on the database.

```
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

`ExecuteReader` used when you want to retrieve the data from database like in `SELECT` query.

Also please use *parameterized* query to avoid Sql Injection

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO notes ([time], [Header], [importance], [body]) VALUES (@time, @header, @importance, @body);";

cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value));
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@header", textBox1.Text);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@importance", Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text));
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@body", textBox2.Text);

cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: you did not created Command obj and did not assigned query and connection obj to Command Constructor like                              SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(sql,con); so how can you call ExecuteNonQuery() method befor initiating instance of command class and passing referance.

Comment: @Muhammad we are not here to writing the complete code. we just put solution of the problem. Rest of the things done by OP. So here I just focused on the problem and its solution, not on writing the complete code.

Comment: ok I can understand but if there is new user who want the solution and unable to understand the flow of your code then what that's becuse I comment of your code... Thanks @Sachin

Answer (score 0):

am not really a c-sharp programmer but you actually shouldn't assign cmd.executeReader() to a variable I think you should just write the command on that line so it executes

Answer (score 0):

try something like this hope it helps

```
OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = Database.accdb");
        conn1.Open();
        string sql = "INSERT INTO notes ([time], [Header], [importance], [body]) " + "VALUES (?,?,?,?);";
        OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn1);
        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@time", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Parse(dateTimePicker1.Value);
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Header", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@importance", OleDbType.Integer).Value = int.Parse(comboBox1.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@body", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
        try
        {
            status = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn1.Close();
            if (status > 0)
                MessageBox.Show("INSERT Command Executed Successfully!");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("INSERT Command Failed!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        this.Close();
```

Answer (score -1):

you can't use cmd2.ExecuteReader to insert the record into database you have to use cmd2.ExcuteNonQuery(); to perform operation such as INSERT UPDATE OR DELETE.

```
OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = Database.accdb");
      conn1.Open();
    string sql = "INSERT INTO notes ([time], [Header], [importance], [body]) VALUES ('" + dateTimePicker1.Value + "', '" + textBox1.Text + "','" + int.Parse(comboBox1.Text) + "','" + textBox2.Text + "');";
    OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn1);
    try
    {
       cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        
        MessageBox.Show("Added");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
    conn1.Close();
    }
```

Comment: `OleDbDataReader rd2 = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();`  does it even compile ?

Comment: code generate exeception and caught by or handle by catch block

Comment: try to write above line in your editor. It will not even compile. No exception occurs until code runs.